# php login throttling by detecting ALL failed attempts per minute

Tags: php, authentication

**Background info:** I have a website with small number of members. The page is in pure php7 + html + css. No javascipt, no databases. I use json to keep user info. I send Content Security Policy script-src 'none' header so i cannot use any javascript. I am a new programmer so I like keeping things simple.

**What I want:** Somehow log ALL failed login attempts (from ALL ips) and if i get >30 failed login attempts per minute then throttle login (say) by n seconds. This would protect me against bruteforce by proxy hopping as well as bruteforcing from a single ip. How should I implement this?

**What to avoid:** If I write failed login attemps to a file then there should be some check to make sure that the file is not growing too rapidly. I do not want to DOS myself trying to write constantly to a growing file. Also how should I delete old entries?

**Edit:** What I need is not code but an algorithm of achieving this.

An idea I have involves two files: failed_attemts.txt and status.txt. (Or json.) The first file contains time stamps of failed attemps and the second one contains a single line to indicate whether the server is in regular mode or throttling mode.

Every time a failed attempt happens do the following:

1. Check status.txt to see if we are in regular mode or throttling mode. If throttling, stay throttling. Else do the following:
2. Append the time of the failed attempt as a new line to "failed_attemts.txt".
3. Delete all lines that has time stamps older than one minute to keep the file size small.
4. Check the file if there are >30 lines.
5. If no continue as usual.
6. If yes then go to into throttling mode and indicate it in status.txt.

Throttling mode will simply consist of delaying the process of the login form by n seconds. I can add more fancy throttling methods later on if needed.

I also need to write the beginning time of the throttling mode in status.txt so that I can leave the throttling mode after (say) 30 minutes (in step 1 above).

The only weak point that I can see in this algorithm is that during a bruteforce attack the file status.txt is repeatedly read. But probably linux (ubuntu 16.04) will cache it into memory so it would be ok. (Am I right in this assumption?)

Would my algorithm work? Any improvements? Better algorithms?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Just curious - how does your website handle login, when no javascript, no databases?

Comment: I keep usernames and hashes of passwords in a json file. I have a POST form where the user can submit username and pasword. I look in the json file to get the password hash of the username and use the php built-in password_verify function to see if the password submitted is valid. Then I use SESSION to keep logged in status.

Comment: OK @skolem, thanks. Anyway, Have you implemented any solutions? If not, this question appears to be too broad, as there are too many possible answers.

Comment: I have implemented nothing yet. Any suggestions, ideas, or pointers will guide me how to implement. I dont know where to start.

Comment: Well, before continuing I would suggest you to learn practices how to post a good question. Try to post what you've tried first. The public will neither want to type the code for you nor giving you possible solution if you haven't tried any. Show eventual troubles you are having and you are likely to get good answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: OK. Thank you. I will edit and try to ask a more concrete question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you'd like in JSON, but be aware that it will be a lot slower than using a database if your site grows to have lots of activity.

**Record failed login attempts and the throttle marker in JSON:**

```
{
    "throttleUntil":0,

    "failedLogins": [
        {
            "time": 1234567,
            "ip": "123.123.123.123",
            "user": "linda"
        },
        {
            "time": 1234569,
            "ip": "123.123.123.123",
            "user": "eric"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Process all logins**

- Read the file and JSON decode into an array
- Check `throttleUntil`. If its value is in the future (`> time()`), it means logins are temporarily suspended; deny login attempt.

**Process each failed login attempt**

- Apply [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to `failedLogins` to keep only those logins within the last minute (or whatever period you want to watch)
- Add the failed login to the resulting array
- If # of array elements reached the limit (eg 30 logins), suspend logins for n seconds by setting `throttleUntil = time() + n`
- JSON encode the array and save the file

Because you used `array_filter` then worked with and saved the resulting array, your log will not grow indefinitely. At any time, it will hold only the last minute's worth of failed logins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make json files for all IPs that are trying to log in. The first thing you need to do before you check the entered credentials is to read the json file for their IP and check the last connection timestamps.

If you see they tried too often you can just show some error message or what I really like is to send them [Gzip bombs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38766622/1174516) (for extreme cases) that might crash their browser or tool.